# Top level links are not clickable in superfish

Tags: jquery, wordpress, superfish

I used Superfish v1.6.2 for drop down menu in WordPress Theme. Menu is working fine, But the top level menu links which contains the submenu are not working/click-able.

There you will notice that "Portfolio" and "Sample Page" link not working. Please help me that how Can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://oi45.tinypic.com/2cncowg.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used something like the following for the same issue with a jquery menubar.  Perhaps this can help you as well.

```
        $("#menu li a").click(function () {
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
            return false;
        });
```

Essentially this grabs the location from the top-level menu item link and navigates to it.  The "return false" cancels further processing of the popout menu under the top-level.

Good luck.